# Expression "variable, variable = value;"

Tags: c++, comma-operator

I have been looking through some MFC code and i came across this expression. It was in OnInitDialog() function, didn't look like it's MFC specific. The variables had some name, value was 0.

```
int volatile something, somethingElse; //this was global

something, somethingElse = 0; //this was inside the function
```

Does this make any sense in C++? I know how the comma operator works, though in a free form like here it should be separating expressions. Is a variable name also an expression? This code does compile, so how does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely an error in the program.  The statement

```
a, b = c;
```

Is completely equivalent to

```
b = c;
```

Since the comma operator evaluates from left to right and discards all values except the last.  Since the expression a has no side effects, it's essentially a no-op.

I would suspect that this is either programmer error or an incorrect translation of code from a different language into C++.  You should contact the author to let them know about this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is worthwhile to mention that it is most likely an error in the program since the variables in question are declared *global*. If that was not the case, the statement could be used to avoid *unused variable* warning on `a`(assuming it is never used in the program but probably just received as a function param) and assign `b` to `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Legal but questionable. The part before the comma doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this make any sense in C++?

Yes syntactically it does, but without comments you may not know the developers intentions were (if any) other than maybe suppressing a variable warning.

> Is a variable name also an expression?

Yes a variable itself is an expression. Ex. `if(<expression>) if(something)`

> This code does compile, so how does this work?

It works by using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and ignoring the result of `something` then assigning 0 to `somethingElse`. Although `something` was marked `volatile` the original developer may of had a compiler that still complained about unused variables and being the clever developer he or she was then decided to suppress with that syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
something, somethingElse = 0;
```

probably, it is done to avoid the unused variable warning on variable `somethin`g an to initialize the `somethingElse` variable to `0`.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable explanation! And for the idea, actually :) I use self-assignment (`a=a`) to supress those warnings, but some IDEs (e. g. Eclipse CDT) don't like it.

Comment: I thought about the unused variable warning too, but it doesn't seem to apply in this case - the variable is global.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You spotted the cheeky comment that I missed :) Well spotted actually.